# Python Bootstrap Error: Can't Start New Thread with only two threads running

Tags: python, multithreading, bootstrapping

From what I've gather by looking through the website, the following error is due to the program having too many threads open and hitting some sort of resource barrier.

`_start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
error: can't start new thread`

The fact that it's creating too many thread would be all fine and dandy and would be an acceptable reason, except I'm only trying to run two threads. These threads are countdown timers.

When clicking the first button to start the first timer, it gives me this error but the timer still starts running. When I click on the second button to start the second timer, it gives me this error then crashes the program.

Here's the relevant code.

```
def OB():
t1 = Thread(target = OB)
t1.start()
OBx = 300
for x in xrange(1, 300):
    OwnBlue.configure(text = "Own Blue Is Up In " + str(OBx) + " Seconds.")
    OBx = OBx - 1
    time.sleep(1)
    root.update()
def OR():
t2 = Thread(target = OR)
t2.start()
ORx = 300
for x in xrange(1, 300):
    OwnRed.configure(text = "Own Red Is Up In " + str(ORx) + " Seconds.")
    ORx = ORx - 1
    time.sleep(1)
    root.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Aight guys I figured dis here program out.

When you target a function with a thread, you also run the function. So because the thread was within the function, the function was infinitely being run.